# How do I specify an integer literal of type unsigned char in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, constants, language-lawyer

I can specify an integer literal of type unsigned long as follows:

```
const unsigned long example = 9UL;
```

How do I do likewise for an unsigned char?

```
const unsigned char example = 9U?;
```

This is needed to avoid compiler warning:

```
unsigned char example2 = 0;
...
min(9U?, example2);
```

I'm hoping to avoid the verbose workaround I currently have and not have 'unsigned char' appear in the line calling min without declaring 9 in a variable on a separate line:

```
min(static_cast<unsigned char>(9), example2);
```

Comment: I changed your question slightly to what i think your intention was. Things like `10` are called "literals" in C++ (while being called "constants" in C). It's more common to C++ folks and avoids confusion with declaration of "example".

Comment: **TL;DR:** Easiest to use and read: `char(9)` `uchar(9)`

Comment: @Andrew `uchar`?

Comment: @Mr Lister potato?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

C++11 introduced user defined literals. It can be used like this:

```
inline constexpr unsigned char operator "" _uchar( unsigned long long arg ) noexcept
{
    return static_cast< unsigned char >( arg );
}

unsigned char answer()
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::min( 42, answer() );        // Compile time error!
    std::cout << std::min( 42_uchar, answer() );  // OK
}
```

Comment: OP, make this the accepted answer already! Though I'd advise using just `_uc`, for conciseness as well as parity with the standard `ul` and so on.

Answer (score 32):

C provides no standard way to designate an integer constant with width less that of type `int`.

However, `stdint.h` does provide the `UINT8_C()` macro to do something that's pretty much as close to what you're looking for as you'll get in C.

But most people just use either no suffix (to get an `int` constant) or a `U` suffix (to get an `unsigned int` constant). They work fine for char-sized values, and that's pretty much all you'll get from the `stdint.h` macro anyway.

Comment: As of glibc 2.26, UINT8_C doesn't give you a 8 bit integer: ```# define UINT8_C(c) c```

Answer (score 26):

You can cast the constant.  For example:

```
min(static_cast<unsigned char>(9), example2);
```

You can also use the constructor syntax:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
min(uchar(9), example2);
```

The typedef isn't required on all compilers.

Comment: I think you are the only one that decrypted his pretty secret question correctly. Firstly, i didn't figure out either what he really wanted to ask.

Comment: Right, that is my current work around, with this question I was hoping to avoid the cast, but it sounds like the answer is there is no literal that will allow me to avoid the cast.

Comment: with the constructor syntax, does this cause an object allocation every time as opposed to the literal?

Comment: @RaviNankani It's  a constructor syntax for a primitive type, so there is should be no overhead.

Comment: I'd write something like this (as the **uint8_t** typedef has been part of the standard since C++11): `min(uint8_t{9}, example2);`

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Visual C++ and have no need for interoperability between compilers, you can use the **ui8** suffix on a number to make it into an unsigned 8-bit constant.

```
min(9ui8, example2);
```

You can't do this with actual char constants like '9' though.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that you are using `std::min` what you actually should do is explicitly specify what type `min` should be using as such

```
unsigned char example2 = 0;
min<unsigned char>(9, example2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply `const unsigned char example = 0;` will do fine.

Comment: That's an `int` literal, implicitly cast down to a unsigned char (const), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `'\0'` would be a char literal with the value 0, but I don't see the point either.

Comment: This is not unsigned char, but signed char.

Comment: @WilliamKF: the type of `'\0'` in C++ is neither `signed char` not `unsigned char`, it is `char` as Axel says. `char` is unlike other integral types: `signed int` and `int` are the same type, but `signed char` and `char` are not.

Comment: I thought `char` was implicitly the same as `signed char`, but I may be thinking of C...

Comment: @ScottSmith, it's the same thing in C, also three distinct types. It's implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no suffix for unsigned char types. Integer constants are either `int` or `long` (`signed` or `unsigned`) and in C99 `long long`. You can use the plain 'U' suffix without worry as long as the value is within the valid range of unsigned chars.

Answer (score -3):

The question was how to "specify an integer 'literal' of type unsigned char in C++?".  Not how to declare an identifier.

You use the escape backslash and octal digits in apostrophes.  (eg.  '\177')

The octal value is always taken to be unsigned.

Comment: No it's not taken to be unsigned, it's still `char` — neither `unsigned char` nor `signed char`.