# How can a template function get max of an int or a char

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class MyType>
MyType GetMax (MyType a, MyType b, MyType c) {
  return std::max(std::max(a, b), c);
}

int main () {
  int a = 5, b = 6, c = 7, d;
  char e [] = "1", f [] = "2", g [] = "3", h; 
  d=GetMax<int>(a,b,c);
  cout << d << endl;
}
```

error: no matching function for call to 'GetMax(char [2], char [2], char [2])'

The program works fine with int but i am not sure what the problem is for char

Comment: remove `<int>` in `GetMax<int>(a,b,c)` and let it deduce types for u. also if u use it with `char*`s it will compare pointers not content. if u want to compare content of strings use `std::string` (or modify ur func to take a comparator)

Comment: Related (because `std::max` isn't liking my `char` vs. `int` comparison): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304732/how-do-i-specify-an-integer-literal-of-type-unsigned-char-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring C-style *strings*, nor `char`s.

If you want to use `GetMax` with `char`s your code should be something like this:

```
 char e = '1', f = '2', g = '3', h; 
 h = GetMax<char>(e, f, g);
```

Note that in this particular case the compiler can determine the signature for GetMax, so you can reduce the call to just:

```
 h = GetMax(e, f, g);
```

Comment: Or `char e = 1, f = 2, g = 3, h;`. Who knows.

Comment: @DyP: sure - that's possible too.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a problem with `char`, it has a problem with `char *`, also known as "c-style strings".

There is no `operator<` for c-style strings (char *), so `std::max` doesn't work. You'll have to implement it yourself with `strcmp` OR use `std::string` instead.

Comment: actually yes there is `operator<` for pointers, i thikn the problem is he explicitly specified the template arg instead of letting it deduce it or giving the right type

Comment: @kal fine, there is. But not the one he wanted... :p